# Problematic understanding of IEEE 754

Tags: c, floating-point, ieee-754

First of all i woild like to point out that i am not native speaker and i really need some terms used more commonly.

And the second thing i would like to mention is that i am not a math genious. I am really trying to understand everything about programming.. but ieee-754 makes me think that it'll never happan.. its full of mathematical terms i don't understand..

---

What is precision? What is it used for? What is mantissa and what is mantissa used for? How to determine the range of `float`/`double` by their size? What is ± symbol (Plus-minus) used for? (i believe its positive/negative choice but what does that have to do with everything?),

Isn't there any brief and clean explanation you guys could provide me with?
I spent 600 years of trying to understand wikipedia. I failed tremendously.

Comment: there is plenty of info on the internet, eg http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/

Comment: How is that helping me at all?

Comment: In your 600 years on wikipedia, did you happen to see [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)?

Comment: Not to insult you but .. http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/the-real-difference-between-integers-and-floatingp.html

Comment: What is your native language? From the [main Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) on the subject, select your preferred language from the language menu at the left-hand side bar.  They are not direct translations of each other, but separately authored.  You may fair better with one in your own language.

Comment: I want more downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is precision?

It refers to how closely a binary floating point representation can represent a *real* value. Real values have infinite precision and infinite range. Digital values have finite range and precision.  In practice a *single-precision* IEEE-754 can represent real values of a precision of 6 significant figures (decimal), while *double-precision* is good for 15 significant figures.

The practical effect of this for example is that a single precision value: `123456000.00` cannot be distinguished from say `123456001.00`, but equally a value 0.00123456 can be represented.

> What is it used for?

*Precision* is not used for anything other than to define a characteristic of a particular floating point representation.

> What is mantissa and what is mantissa used for?

The term is not mentioned in the English language Wikipedia article, and is imprecise - in mathematics in general it has a different meaning that that used here.

The correct term is *significand*.  For a decimal value `0.00123456` for example the significand is is `123456`. `123456000.00` has exactly the same significand.  Each of these values has the same *significand* but a different *exponent*.  The exponent is a *scaling factor* which determines where the decimal point is (hence *floating* point).

Of course IEEE754 is a *binary floating point* representation not decimal, but for the same of explanation of the terms it is perhaps easier to use decimal.

> How to determine the range of float/double by their size?

By the size alone you cannot; you need to know how many bits are assigned to the *significand* and how many bits are assigned to the *exponent*.  In C however the range is defined by the macros `FLT_MIN`, `FLT_MAX`, `DBL_MIN` and `DBL_MAX` in the [float.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cfloat/) header.  Other characteristics of the implementations floating point representation are described there also.

Note that a specific compiler may not in fact use IEEE754, however that is the format used by most hardware FPU implementations, and the compiler will naturally follow that.  For targets with no FPU (small embedded processors typically), other formats may be used.

> What is ± symbol (Plus-minus) used for?

It simply means that the value given may be both positive or negative.  It may refer to a specific value, or it may indicate a range.  So ±n may refer to two discrete values -n *or* +n, or it may mean a range -n *to* +n.  Context is everything!  In [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) it refers to discrete values +0, -0, +∞ and -∞.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll be re-reading this.

Comment: But assuming the datatype `float` is 4 bytes..
Can't i calculate the range/maximum ?

Comment: @Compiled : That is 32 bits, you need to know how those are distributed amongst significand and exponent to determine the range.  IEEE754 binary32 format specifies 24 bit significand, 8 bits exponent and 1 sign bit.  It is these figures from which you can calculate the range, but there is little need, the number of bits are standardised so the range is standardised too.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 different components: sign, exponent, mantissa

Assuming that the exponent has only 2 Bits, 4 combinations are possible:

```
binary decimal
00     0
01     1
10     2
11     3
```

The represented floating-point value is 2<sup>exponent</sup>:

```
binary exponent-value
00     2^0 = 1
01     2^1 = 2
10     2^2 = 4
11     2^3 = 8
```

The range of the floating point value, results from the exponent. 2 bits => maximum value = 8.

The mantissa divide the range from a given exponent to the next higher exponent.
For example the exponent is 2 and the mantissa has one bit, then there are two values possible:

```
exponent-value  mantissa-binary  represented floating-point value
2               0                2
2               1                3
```

The represented floating-point value is 2<sup>exponent</sup> × (1 + m1×2<sup>-1</sup> + m2×2<sup>-2</sup> + m3×2<sup>-3</sup> + …).
Here an example with a 3 bit mantissa:

```
exponent-value  mantissa-binary  represented floating-point value
2               000              2 * (1                      ) = 2
2               001              2 * (1                + 2^-3) = 2,25
2               010              2 * (1         + 2^-2       ) = 2,5
2               011              2 * (1         + 2^-2 + 2^-3) = 2,75
2               100              2 * (1 + 2^-1               ) = 3
and so on…
```

The sign has only just one Bit:
0 -> positive value
1 -> negative value

In IEEE-754 a 32 bit floating-point data type has an 8 bit exponent (with a range from 2<sup>-127</sup> to 2<sup>128</sup>) and a 23 bit mantissa.

```
1 10000010 01101000000000000000000
- 130      1,40625
```

The represented floating-point value for this is:
-1 × 2<sup>(130 – 127)</sup> × (1 + 2<sup>-2</sup> + 2<sup>-3</sup> + 2<sup>-5</sup>) = -11,25

Try it: http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html

Comment: In IEEE754 the more accurate term *significand* is used rather than *mantissa*.  Even the linked converter page has confused the terms, saying *"mantissa (also known as significand or fraction)*", but "fraction" is the correct mathematical meaning of *mantissa* and not its meaning here.  You have also somewhat glossed over the fact that the exponent itself is signed - only introducing that indirectly at the end.